# pyspark_cassandra importing issue in pyspark with spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.3.0-M2 jar

Tags: python, cassandra, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using *Spark* 1.3.0 and want to connect *Cassandra* using *Pyspark*. 
 
`>pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.3.0-M2`

It is showing successfully downloading the dependency jars and getting into the Pyspark terminal, but I am not able to do the imports.

```
>>> from pyspark_cassandra import CassandraSparkContext, Row <br/> 
Tracstrong texteback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: No module named pyspark_cassandra
```

I have also tried with

```
sudo -u hdfs pyspark --packages TargetHolding:pyspark-cassandra:0.1.5
```

and also with assembeled jars using `--jars option`. Still the same. The same works well with spark-shell, using scala. I am new to python.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should set your PYTHONPATH this way :

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/ilias/apache-spark/1.3.0
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: I can see the following path variables in the pyspark terminal, but still not able to import the pyspark_cassandra module. <br/> >>> os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None) <br/> 
'/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.4-1.cdh5.4.4.p0.4/lib/spark' <br/> 
>>> os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', None) <br/>
'/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.4-1.cdh5.4.4.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.4-1.cdh5.4.4.p0.4/lib/spark/python/:/opt/
cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.4-1.cdh5.4.4.p0.4/lib/spark/python/build' <br/>

Answer (score 0):

There is no packages release for 1.3.0-M2

The only release on spark-packages at the moment is 1.4.0-M3

Check the link below for the current packages

http://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Once you are running it the way to access C* is via the Dataframes API

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md

Comment: Tried this: pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.4.0-M3. Still the same error. do i need to import the pyspark_cassandra module separately?

Comment: They above import gives you access to the Dataframes api, see the doc link.

Comment: But i am not able to do: >import pyspark_cassandra from pyspark terminal.

Comment: You don't do that. Please read the link.

You just create dataframes like
sqlContext.read.source("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")...load()

Comment: Okay, so dataframes are extending RDD functionalities right? Again, the doc says 1.4.0-M3 is not compatible with spark 1.3. So do i need to upgrade spark to use the connector jar?